# Routing Twilio SMS Responses in Python for conversational bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sms, twilio

I'm a university student relatively new to Python programming. I have been trying to build a conversational bot that allows a user to schedule appointments via SMS in Python.

I have been following many Python Twilio SMS tutorials online such as the [official](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python) Twilio guide. I cannot figure out how to route a Twilio SMS response to the corresponding route. For example, a user is supposed to text in either `SCHEDULE`, `RESCHEDULE`, `CHECK`, or `DROP`, and the application is supposed to route them to the corresponding route with some logic to process the request (and reply with a further SMS message). If they do not enter one of the four specified words, the application is supposed to reroute the user back to the `/inbound` route to ask them to again clarify that they are selecting one of the four acceptable options. I have really been struggling hard for the past couple of days on this, getting confused on `routes` and whether or not to use the `message = client.messages.create` or `response = MessagingResponse()` Twilio APIs. I am using Flask to handle the web server capabilities.

Also, would you happen to know how to pass a parameter through the `redirect` route so that I can use that data in the next route and save it in a database?

Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate all the help I can get.

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Body, Message, Redirect, MessagingResponse
from flask import Flask, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)


# Main function triggered by a POST request by ngrok. When an SMS is received, Twilio will send the POST.
@app.route('/inbound', methods=['POST'])
def inbound():
    """ Use Twilio API to reply to texts """
    sender = request.form['From']
    message = request.form['Body']
    recipient = request.form['To']              # Recipient Phone Number
    message_id = request.form['MessageSid']     # Twilio message id
    response = MessagingResponse()              # init a Twilio response
    formatted = message.lower().strip()         # formulate answer to message
    if "schedule" == formatted:
        reply = 'Hi, my name is Cletus. I\'d like to help you schedule your appointment today. What is your name? ' \
                'Please format \"First Last\" (ex: John Smith).'
        response.message(reply)
        response.redirect('/schedule')
        # write to db
    elif "reschedule" == formatted:
        reply = 'Hi, my name is Cletus. I\'d like to help you reschedule your appointment today. What is your name? ' \
                'Please format \"First Last\" (ex: John Smith).'
        response.message(reply)
        response.redirect('/reschedule')
    elif "appointments" == formatted:
        reply = 'Hi, my name is Cletus. I\'d like to help you check your upcoming appointment. What is your name? ' \
                'Please format \"First Last\" (ex: John Smith).'
        response.message(reply)
        response.redirect('/check')
    elif "drop" == formatted:
        reply = 'Hi, my name is Cletus. I\'d like to help you cancel your appointment. What is your name? ' \
                'Please format \"First Last\" (ex: John Smith).'
        response.message(reply)
        response.redirect('/drop')
    else:
        reply = 'Hi, my name is Cletus. How can I help you? You can text RESCHEDULE to reschedule you appointment, ' \
                'DROP to cancel your appointment, and APPOINTMENTS to receive a list of your currently scheduled ' \
                'appointments. Have a great day!'
        response.message(reply)
        response.redirect('/inbound')
    return str(response)


@app.route('/schedule', methods=['POST'])
def schedule():
    print('Finally routing to schedule')
    sender = request.form['From']
    message = request.form['Body']
    recipient = request.form['To']  # Recipient Phone Number
    message_id = request.form['MessageSid']  # Twilio message id
    response = MessagingResponse()  # init a Twilio response
    formatted = message.lower().strip()


@app.route('/reschedule', methods=['POST'])
def reschedule():
    sender = request.form['From']
    message = request.form['Body']
    recipient = request.form['To']  # Recipient Phone Number
    message_id = request.form['MessageSid']  # Twilio message id
    response = MessagingResponse()  # init a Twilio response
    formatted = message.lower().strip()


@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    sender = request.form['From']
    message = request.form['Body']
    recipient = request.form['To']  # Recipient Phone Number
    message_id = request.form['MessageSid']  # Twilio message id
    response = MessagingResponse()  # init a Twilio response
    formatted = message.lower().strip()


@app.route('/drop', methods=['POST'])
def cancel():
    sender = request.form['From']
    message = request.form['Body']
    recipient = request.form['To']  # Recipient Phone Number
    message_id = request.form['MessageSid']  # Twilio message id
    response = MessagingResponse()  # init a Twilio response
    formatted = message.lower().strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Do you need to redirect Twilio if all you're doing in each redirected route is fetch the smae data and return the same response? Could this all be done within your initial method?

Comment: Update: I figured out all I needed was to use Python Sessions.